# ruby: search an multi-dimensional array for a value and update if needed

Tags: ruby, search, multidimensional-array

Trying to look through an array and see if a particular value is set and if it is, update the numbers attached to it.

Example:

```
test = [['test',1,2],['watch',1,2],['fish',1,2]]
```

So I'd like to search this array for 'test' - if it exists, amend the values '1,2', if it doesn't exist, just add the new search term into the array.

New to ruby and having trouble searching inside a multi-dimensional array and getting the key back

Comment: Why do you use Array not Hash?

Comment: Like I said, Im new to Ruby - as I understand it a Hash would just form an associative array instead of a numerical one? I'm not seeing how that would help me search inside the multi-dimensional array. It's not a key=>value relationship, there's 3 terms inside each subarray

Comment: mmm and if you use sth like `test = [ :test=>[1,2], :watch => [1,2], :fish => [1,2] ]`

Comment: Aye just realised that as I went for a quick walk round the block. Will give it a whirl, thanks for putting me onto this tack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go for the hash method suggested in the comments, but if you're really wanting to store your data in the multidimensional array like that I suppose you could do something like:

```
search_term = "test"
search_item= nil
test.each do |item|
  if item.include? search_term
    search_item = item
  end
end

if search_item.nil?
  test << [search_term]
else
  search_item << [1,2]
end
```

I think that would do it (although I'm a little fuzzy on what you were wanting to do after you found the item).

Comment: I did indeed go with the Hash method in the end. This method does look workable as well though and is technically the answer to the initial question